# How to clear search input field with javascript when using Google Maps v3 Autocomplete Form

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using Google maps v3 api to autocomplete an address form but I do not want to use a general search field like in the example (https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete-addressform).

I am trying to make the street address field the search field as well as the **street number and street name field only**. I found this example on JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/smartystreets/0c9fy73v/) I cannot replicate it.

I tried turning autocomplete=off but does not work on chrome (for elementId('autocomplete'))

I tried hiding the route and street input elements and setting the input id value to empty.

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = '';
```

Then using the hidden input fields to rebuild that form input w/

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = document.getElementById('street_number') + ' ' + document.getElementById('route');
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Why wont the search field clear?

This is my HTML for my search/address field:

```
<!-- address -->
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <label class="light text-capitalize">address:</label>
      <input type="text"   id="autocomplete"
         name="street" placeholder="Street address, PO Box, etc.">
      <input type="hidden" id="route" disabled="false">
      <input type="hidden" id="street_number" disabled="false"> 
      <input type="text"  name="address1" placeholder="(Optional) Apartment, Suite, Floor, etc.">
   </div>
<!-- address end -->
```

This is my inline JS

```
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
     street_number: 'short_name',
     route: 'long_name',
     locality: 'long_name',
     administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
     postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();


    for (var component in componentForm) {

    document.getElementById('street_number').value = '';
    document.getElementById('route').value = '';
    document.getElementById('locality').value = '';
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value = '';
//  document.getElementById('country').value = '';
    document.getElementById('postal_code').value = '';

    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
   for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
       var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: when do you want to clear the search field?

Comment: Hi James, i want to clear it after the user clicks on the address that matches their search

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to clear the search input field after the user clicks on the address from autocomplete, try setting the input (id=autocomplete) value to empty after you get the place.

```
function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    /* Your other code */

    document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = '';
}
```

I just made a demonstration for you to check the behavior. You can see it here http://jsbin.com/mugasav/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: James you are a legend. Works perfectly as intended, i pounded my head against the wall for hours trying to figure it out!

Comment: If my answer helped you, you could also accept my answer so that it could help me and others as well :)

Comment: this should have more upvotes, saved me from an ugly hack with autocomplete reinitialization